# Average amplitude of pulse oximetery signal using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, rate, amplitude

I need the average amplitude and the rate of the signal that I recorded from the surface of the body. I wrote the code below but I don't know whether it is really correct.

```
 x=shbo2(1:600); %signal

 psdest = psd(spectrum.periodogram,x,'fs',20,'NFFT',length(x));
 pwr = avgpower(psdest)
```

And for rate of signal, I calculated the peak to peak distance

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(x);
peakInterval = diff(locs);
mean(peakInterval)
```

are those solutions right? 
Thanks

Comment: For a start, from the docs *"avgpower is not recommended.  Use bandpower instead."* Aside from that, questions asking "is this right" are off topic here. Only *you* know if you're getting the desired results, unless you are extremely explicit about what *is* right, in which case you probably know the answer! The `peakInterval` may underpredict if there is any noise in your signal at all for instance, but that depends which "peak" you're measuring

Comment: Could you please let me know when I write the code but I am not sure if the technique is right ( the way that I tried to calculate mean amplitude), how can I ask it?

Comment: Please try to validate your output manually. Plot the signals and the peaks and check if they are correctly detected.